# Flutter Get firebase collection data to list of object

Tags: list, flutter, class, object, addition

I have a class name Todo

```
class TodoField {
  static const createdTime = 'createdTime';
}

class Todo {
  DateTime createdTime;
  String title;
  String id;
  String description;
  bool isDone;

  Todo({
    @required this.createdTime,
    @required this.title,
    this.description = '',
    this.id,
    this.isDone = false,
  });
}
```

My data is saved in collection name: MyTodos.   I want to add a collection in a list like `List<Todo> _todo=[Todo...]`

Answer (score 3):

I'd advise creating a **fromJson** factory method to this **Todo** class, that way mapping the Firebase documents' data to a strongly-typed PODO (Plain Ol' Dart Object) is easier to manipulate in Flutter.

Your updated **Todo** class would look like:

```dart
class Todo {
  DateTime createdTime;
  String title;
  String id;
  String description;
  bool isDone;

  Todo({
    @required this.createdTime,
    @required this.title,
    this.description = '',
    this.id,
    this.isDone = false,
  });

  factory Todo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Todo(
       createdTime: json['createdTime'],
       title: json['title'],
       id: json['id'],
       description: json['description'],
       isDone: json['isDone']
    );
  }
}
```

Then, wherever you're pulling the Firebase data from your collection ** MyTodos**, you should do the mapping, as such:

```dart
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('MyTodos').get();

List<Todo> _todos = snapshot.docs.map((d) => Todo.fromJson(d.data())).toList();
```

Then  you can do anything you want with your **_todos** collection. For example, inside a provided service, you can grab the data as follows:

```dart
class TodosProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

   Future<List<Todo>> GetData() async {
       QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('MyTodos').get(); 
       List<Todo> _todos = snapshot.docs.map((d) => Todo.fromJson(d.data())).toList();
       return _todos;
   }
}
```

Then in your widget's **build** method you can consume this provider as such:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 
 // obtain the provided service
 // make sure this service is injected at the root via 
 // either a ChangeNotifierProvider or MultiProvider
 var todos = Provider.of<TodosProvider>(context, listen: false);

 return Scaffold(
    body: FutureBuilder(
       future: todos.GetData(),
       builder: (context, snapshot) {

         if (snapshot.hasData) {
            // here consume your Todos
            List<Todo> todos = snapshot.data as List<Todo>;

            // put them in a list or whatever you want
         }

         return CircularProgressIndicator();

       }
    )
 );

}
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer. I added mapping in function as : 
class TodosProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

  Future<List<Todo>> GetData ()
  async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('MyTodos').get();
    List<Todo> _todos = snapshot.docs.map((d) => Todo.fromJson(d.data())).toList();
    return _todos;
  }

  List<Todo> _todos = GetData() as List<Todo> ;  But getting error as instance member GetData can't be accessed in initializer. Do you think there can be any other way to implement it.

Comment: You can do that in the build method for now, but I’d recommend fetching your Firebase collection by using a **FutureBuilder** widget. You are correct in creating this method inside a provider service, so call this a sync method as the **future** of a **FutureBuilder**. Let me know what else you need so as to mark this question as correct, otherwise we can take it up on a separate issue.

Comment: Thanks !! I am new to flutter so little confused. What I expect is to get data from firebase and add it to list of object which is declared in the provider service. In this way, I can use this service in multiple tabs, Your answer is correct but I need implementation in this way.

Comment: Ok, maybe your question could be improved. You asked "I want to add a collection in a list like List<Todo> _todo=[Todo...]" and you already have it. Now. you're asking about a provider service, which is a separate question. See my updated answer and see if that helps.